# Run code on app uninstall

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uninstallation

I've been searching online and can't find too much info about this, so before I waste any more time on it I'd like to ask if it's possible to run code on the uninstall of a cross-platform Xamarin Forms app?

Comment: No.  The app is not notified when the OS uninstalls it.

Comment: If it were possible, imagine the exploit potential. That is a good reason to not allowed the app to act when it gets deleted.

Comment: thanks guys, confirms what I thought

Comment: still curious, what kind of code you want to run on uninstall?

Comment: I store an email address in local storage and use a combination of that plus database info to authenticate, saves the user inputting the email address each time.  If they uninstall, the database entry is still there but the local storage is not so I get an error.  My thinking was to remove the database entry on uninstall, but I have another way round it now.