# Android/ Xamarin android : Call function at the time of app Install and Uninstall

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing one android application in Xamarin android.
Is it possible to call function/ REST API when user install/uninstall app?

Comment: No, look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911480/run-code-on-app-uninstall

Comment: It is impossible due to the system security policy.